# KeyListener not responding to key inputs

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, keylistener

So I have seen a couple of these questions asked. They all say that you should not be using a Keylistener but instead a KeyBinding thing. But when I go to use the Keybinding it does not work. I understand I probably should be using the KeyBinding thing but is there a way that I can fix my code so that the KeyListener works. Thank you.

**Game Class:**

```
public class Game extends JFrame implements KeyListener{
    public static int ppx,ppy;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Game");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(500,600);
        frame.add(new THIng());
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        int keycode = e.getKeyCode();
        if(keycode == KeyEvent.VK_D){
            System.out.println("Debug");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    }

}
```

**THIng Class:**

```
    public class THIng extends JPanel{
    public static int px,py,pwid,phei;

    public void main(String[]args){
        Timer timer;
        timer = new Timer(60,
                new ActionListener(){
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
                        p();
                    }
                }
        );
    }
    public THIng(){

        px = Game.ppx;py = Game.ppy;pwid = 50;phei = pwid;
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize(){
        return new Dimension(500,600);
    }
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics p = (Graphics)g;
        p.drawRect(px,py,pwid,phei);

    }
    public void p(){
        repaint();
    }

}
```

Comment: Like every other question relating to `KeyListener` not working, simply put, don't use it. Use the [Key Bindings API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) instead. For [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33664601/draw-two-line-by-keytyped-event-in-java/33664850#33664850), [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28206950/java-moving-clipping-area-by-keylistener/28207024#28207024), [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16622630/gradually-speeding-a-sprite/16623202#16623202)

Comment: [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13041297/java-moving-an-object-at-an-angle-and-changing-angle-with-keypress/13041547#13041547), [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15145120/key-listeners-key-bindings-in-java/15146987#15146987) ...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

as MadProgrammer has pointed out the right thing to do is use the Key Bindings API which you can see step by step [Key Bindings API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)

add a constructor that adds a key listener and in your main make it class Game instead of JFrame

```
public class Game extends JFrame implements KeyListener{
    public static int ppx,ppy;

    public Game(String string) {
        addKeyListener(this);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Game frame = new Game("Game");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(500,600);
        frame.add(new THIng());

        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        int keycode = e.getKeyCode();
        if(keycode == KeyEvent.VK_D){
            System.out.println("Debug");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }



}
```

Comment: While this might "solve" the question, it propagates the use of the wrong API. Instead of using `KeyListener` which is prone to "not working" at random times (due it's associated focus issues), you should be encouraging the use of the [Key Bindings API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) API instead, which not only solve the "question", but prevent further issues in the future

Comment: i know, its just that he specifically said to make the keyListener work

Comment: So, if you're teaching the OP to shoot, are you just going to show them where the trigger is? We're going to be losing a lot of feet. Sometimes, it's better to point the OP in the right direction to not only solve there immediate problem, but other potential problems they might have in the future (if the continue with their current direction). There's "just answering" the question and there's giving the "right answer". As professionals, we should always provide professional solutions, that's what SO's meant for after all, best practices

Comment: ok ill just delete this then, I don't know how to do key bindings, ill delete it since its now a duplicate

Comment: it says I cant delete it

Comment: Yeah, it's been "accepted".  You could add a foot note, maybe pointing to the key bindings API ;)

Comment: ok, put a note up there, I thought you might say something I think I seen you put up comments on like 10 different questions about using key bindings instead of KeyListener, haha, cant get one past MadProgrammer hahahaha

Comment: It's one of pet hates ;)

Answer (score 0):

you don't have to make a constructor, just add `frame.addKeyListener(this);` where you have set other properties of the JFrame.